# Intermittent blanking monitor with integrated graphics

Tags: graphics-card, bios, motherboard, hdmi, integrated-graphics

I have a motherboard with two HDMI connectors. One of them has no signal, the other one works but blacks out intermittently every few seconds. This is happening on the BIOS screen, so I don't think it's a problem with drivers. The blanking doesn't occur with a dedicated graphics card so I know the monitor is okay. Can the CPU be good while the integrated graphics is bad? Is there a setting in the BIOS that fixes this problem?

Comment: Did you try to use a different HDMI cable? // Did you verify the tight seating of the HDMI connectors at both ends?